# Фильтр таблицы mysql с помощью двух мультиселектов php

Tags: php, mysql

Полный новичок в php и mysql, поэтому прошу помощи и совета в нахождении ошибки.
Есть код

```
        <form method="post" action="routes-ok.php">
        <p>Дата с:</p>
        <input name="date_start" type="date"/>
        <p>Дата по:</p>
        <input name="date_end" type="date"/>
        <p>Фильтр по водителям</p>    
        <select multiple name="drv[]" size="10">
        <?php
        $driverResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT DRIVER FROM DRIVERS WHERE DELETED !=1"); 

         if (! empty($driverResult)) {
               foreach ($driverResult as $key => $value) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $driverResult[$key]['DRIVER'] . '">' . 
         $driverResult[$key]['DRIVER'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>    
        </select>  

        <p>Фильтр по авто</p> 
        <select multiple name="auto[]" size="10">

        <?php
             $autoResult = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT CARNUM FROM CARS WHERE DELETED !=1"); 

         if (! empty($autoResult)) {
               foreach ($autoResult as $key => $value) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $autoResult[$key]['CARNUM'] . '">' . $autoResult[$key]['CARNUM'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>                
        </select>       

       <input type="submit" value="Применить">
```

По двум мультиселектам в форме отправляет запрос на следующую страницу

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['drv']) && isset($_POST['auto'])){
    ?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>Номер</th>
    <th>Водитель</th>
    <th>Машина</th>
    <th>Время</th>
    <th>Адрес</th>
    <th>Пробег</th>
</tr>

        <?php
    $query = "SELECT r.N, d.DRIVER, c.CARNUM, r.TIME, r.ADDRESS, r.ODOMETER
    from ROUTES r 
    inner join DRIVERS d on r.DRIVER = d.N 
    inner join CARS c on r.CAR = c.N";


    $b = 0;
    $selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['drv']);
    $selectedOption = "";
    while ($b < $selectedOptionCount) {
        $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['drv'][$b] . "'";
        if ($b < $selectedOptionCount - 1) {
            $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
        }

        $b ++;
    }


    $y = 0;
    $yselectedOptionCount = count($_POST['auto']);
    $yselectedOption = "";
    while ($y < $yselectedOptionCount) {
        $yselectedOption = $yselectedOption . "'" . $_POST['auto'][$y] . "'";
        if ($y < $yselectedOptionCount - 1) {
            $yselectedOption = $yselectedOption . ", ";
        }

        $y ++;
    }

    $query = $query . " WHERE r.DRIVER in (" . $selectedOption . ") AND r.CAR in (" . $yselectedOption . ")";

    var_dump($query);

   $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
}          

if (! empty($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $result[$key]['N']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $result[$key]['DRIVER']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $result[$key]['CARNUM']; ?>
            </td>
             <td>
                <?php echo $result[$key]['TIME']; ?>
            </td>
             <td>
                <?php echo $result[$key]['ADDRESS']; ?>
            </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $result[$key]['ODOMETER']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    } 
    ?>
    </table>

    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

var_dump($query); выводит результат селекта, поэтому как я понимаю составлен он верно. А вот если подставить var_dump ниже в $result, то возвращается NULL. На экран выводится только шапка таблицы без данных и ошибок.
Вот код функции, которая отвечает за выборку. Пример брал с сайта и переделывал под себя, там все работало с 1 мультиселектом.

```
function runQuery($query) {
                $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
                }       
                if(!empty($resultset))
                return $resultset;
    }
```

Предполагаю, что не подходит код функции runQuery, как его изменить, чтобы все заработало пока не знаю. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А $db_handle у вас как-то определен?

Comment: Да, это подключение к базе, там все работает. И все работает, если делать обычным селектом, а не мультиселектом. Думаю, что все же не могу правильно обработать мультиселект

Comment: Если подробно, то $db_handle = new DBController(); А сам контроллер `class DBController {
 private $host = "127.0.0.1";
 private $user = "drivers";
 private $password = "";
 private $database = "drivers";
 private $conn;
 
        function __construct() {
        $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
 } 
 function connectDB() {
  $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
   $conn->set_charset("utf8");
  return $conn; `

Comment: А сам запрос, если выполнить напрямую в базе, работает?

Comment: Если вместо переменных здесь `" WHERE r.DRIVER in (" . $selectedOption . ") AND r.CAR in (" . $yselectedOption . ")"` написать руками несколько полей из бд, то да, в базе работает. Может хотя бы подскажете что читать и куда копать? Скорее всего работу с массивами, но обычная справочная информация мне не помогла (или я ее не до конца понимаю), а примера с двумя мультиселектами не найду, хотя с одним инфы хватает.

Comment: Я имею в виду этот запрос `SELECT r.N, d.DRIVER, c.CARNUM, r.TIME, r.ADDRESS, r.ODOMETER from ROUTES r inner join DRIVERS d on r.DRIVER = d.N inner join CARS c on r.CAR = c.N WHERE r.DRIVER in ('Игорь', 'Евгений', 'Юрий') AND r.CAR in ('к676мм', 'н777нр')` нормально работает?

Comment: Кстати да, вы правы, такой запрос ничего не отображает. В sql работает запрос вида `SELECT r.N, d.DRIVER, c.CARNUM, r.TIME, r.ADDRESS, r.ODOMETER from ROUTES r inner join DRIVERS d on r.DRIVER = d.N inner join CARS c on r.CAR = c.N WHERE r.DRIVER in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') AND r.CAR in ('1', '2', '3')`

Comment: Получается, что через POST я передаю имя и номер авто, а должен передавать как-то их id?

Comment: Получается, да. У вас в таблице `ROUTES` поля `DRIVER` и `CAR` имеют значения `id`, которые указывают на `id` соответствующих таблиц, а не имена и номера машин.

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо, что помогли разобраться. Правда я пока не пойму как это правильно сделать, но хотя бы видно где ошибка

Comment: Вам в самом запросе нужно выбирать id и имя, то есть `SELECT ID,DRIVER FROM DRIVERS WHERE DELETED !=1`, потом в поле value тега option вместо $driverResult[$key]['DRIVER'] подставить $driverResult[$key]['ID'].

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

Ответ может быть пустым в 2х случаях 
1) нет строк удовлетворяющих запрос
2) в селекте ошибка(твой вариант)
$query - это сам запрос к базе, а не ее ответ и скорее всего в нем ошибка, может даже грамматическая

напиши:

```
echo <br>.$query.<br>;
```

увидишь сам запрос, если не поймешь, в чем проблема напиши сюда этот запрос, разберемся

Comment: если я добавляю echo  $query; и выбираю какие-то строки в двух мультиселектах, то получается запрос вида SELECT r.N, d.DRIVER, c.CARNUM, r.TIME, r.ADDRESS, r.ODOMETER from ROUTES r inner join DRIVERS d on r.DRIVER = d.N inner join CARS c on r.CAR = c.N WHERE r.DRIVER in ('Игорь', 'Евгений', 'Юрий') AND r.CAR in ('к676мм', 'н777нр'). Выше в моем вопросе есть сама переменная $query, она собирается из нескольких частей. Может где-то и сделал ошибку, но я ее в упор не вижу пока что в силу своих знаний